# SQL Query - second ID of a list ordered by date and ID

Tags: sql

I have a SQL database with a list of Customer IDs `CustomerID` and invoices, the specific product purchased in each invoice `ProductID`, the `Date` and the `Income` of each invoice . I need to write a query that will retrieve for each product, which was the second customer who made a purchase

How do I do that?

EDIT:

I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT *,
LEAD(CustomerID) OVER (ORDER BY ProductID, Date) AS 'Second Customer Who Made A Purchase'
FROM a
ORDER BY ProductID, Date ASC
```

However, this query presents multiple results for products that have more than two purchases. Can you advise?

Comment: Please store dates using the `DATE` data type not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: You are correct, I have changed that already but used the old link by mistake. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to write a query that will retrieve for each product, which was the second customer who made a purchase

This sounds like a window function:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productid order by date asc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
where seqnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a2.ProductID,
(
    SELECT a1.CustomerID 
    FROM a a1
    WHERE a1.ProductID = a2.ProductID
    ORDER BY Date asc 
    LIMIT 1,1
) as SecondCustomer
FROM a a2
GROUP BY a2.ProductID
```

Comment: What if I use MS SQL Server 2017 and LIMIT does not exist?